# Twilio Call ending at l1 and not proceeding

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to use twilio programable api to get start a call and gather inputs from the user.

As soon as I hit `/l0` I get the call. It reads out the message perfectly but then without taking a input just gets disconnected.

Can you help as to where I am going wrong with this.

Below is my code:

```
@RestController
public class Twilio {
    
    public static final String ngrokURL ="https://9009-fba3-50e-31d8-e98f-f79f.ngrok-free.app";
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "69afe12";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "2a96";
    
    @GetMapping("/l0")
    public void l0(HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
        com.twilio.Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        String from = "+185xxxxxxxx";
        String to = "+1953xxxxxxxx";
        Call call = Call.creator(new PhoneNumber(to), new PhoneNumber(from), new URI(ngrokURL+"/l1")).create();
    }
    @PostMapping(value="/l1", produces = "text/xml")
    public String l1(HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        
        printOnConsole(request, "l1");
        Say say = new Say.Builder("This is an notification. Press any key to proceed.").build();
        Gather gather = new Gather.Builder().action(ngrokURL+"/l2").method(HttpMethod.POST).say(say).build();
        
        VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().gather(gather).build();
        return response.toXml();
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping(value="/l2", produces = "text/xml")
    public String l2(HttpServletRequest request) {
        printOnConsole(request, "l2");
        Say say = new Say.Builder("Press 1 if you are want to, press 2 for").build();
        Gather gather = new Gather.Builder().action(ngrokURL+"/l3").method(HttpMethod.POST).say(say).timeout(5).build();
        
        VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().gather(gather).build();
        return response.toXml();
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value="/l3", produces = "text/xml")
    public String l3(HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
        printOnConsole(request, "l3");
        Say say = new Say.Builder("Record any message after the beep").build();
        Play play = new Play.Builder(new URI("https://www.soundjay.com/buttons/sounds/beep-01a.mp3")).build();
        Gather gather = new Gather.Builder().action(ngrokURL+"/l4").method(HttpMethod.POST).say(say).play(play).inputs(Input.SPEECH).timeout(5).build();
        
        VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().gather(gather).build();
        return response.toXml();
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value="/l4", produces = "text/xml")
    public String l4(HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
        printOnConsole(request, "l4");
        Hangup hangup = new Hangup.Builder().build();
        VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().hangup(hangup).build();
        return response.toXml();
    }
    
    void printOnConsole(HttpServletRequest request, String function){
        if(request==null) {
            return;
        }
        Enumeration<String> enumeration = request.getParameterNames();
        while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
            String parameterName = enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println(function + "--------" +parameterName + "-------------"+ request.getParameter(parameterName));
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried putting `GET` method, using the `finishOnKey`,`timeout`, but none of them seem to change the behavior.